# Linked lists in Django Admin and Foreign key model

Tags: python, foreign-keys, django-admin, chained-select

I have some chained foreign key relationships like this:

```
class Continent(models.Model):
    continent = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Country(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)

class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
```

Is it strictly necessary to have continent and country fields into Person class to make chained select work? 
I would like that Person model stores only city foreign key, but in admin edit form I would like to show continent/country/city chained select.

Comment: Just storing the city is best. The easiest option is to include the continent and country in the `__str__` method of the city so you can look it up easily, but this can quickly get overwhelming. Perhaps use `django-select2` for ajax filtering. Another option is to have a custom form that only populates the next field based on selection in previous, but then only stores the city. And FYI, some countries span continents (eg. Russia, Turkey), so be careful.

Comment: How can I achieve the goal using custom forms?

Comment: Have a custom form with country and continent fields, but don't store the data anywhere, only the city. When loading the page you can populate the fields simply by looking up `person.city.country` and `person.city.country.continent`. The tricky part is using javascript to filter out options when the level above is selected.